# How to run unsafe code in "visual studio code"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, unsafe

I am using Visual studio code and when I try to run an unsafe code it throws the following error ""message": Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe"

and as in visual studio, it does not have option like project->properties.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[unsafe (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option)

> 1. To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment Open the project's Properties page.
>
>    1. Click the Build property page.
>    2. Select the Allow Unsafe Code check box.
> 2. To add this option in a csproj file Open the .csproj file for a project, and add the following elements:

**XML**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

## Usage

**Method level**

```
unsafe static void FastCopy(byte[] src, byte[] dst, int count)  
{  
    // Unsafe context: can use pointers here.  
}
```

**Inline Block**

```
...

unsafe  
{  
    // Unsafe context: can use pointers here.  
}
```

**Class Level**

```
public unsafe class Blah {}
```

Comment: Note that in the general case a Visual Studio Code C# project may not have a .csproj file. See https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp#_roslyn-and-omnisharp

Answer (score 10):

In the `.csproj` file, just add

`<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`

to any `<PropertyGroup>` block.

**No need** to add anything to `task.json`.

Comment: Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option

Answer (score -2):

All not working in my netcoreapp3.1 C# Project

This helped (in .vscode/tasks.json):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/rest.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary",
                "/unsafe"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
```

works for the 'dotnet build' command, not for the green launch button

also working if executed from the terminal: 'dotnet build -p:unsafe=true'